# Replace and Ignoring

Tags: adobe

I'd to know how can I replace a word of syntax within ignoring the other words

```
addChild(pCircle_f0s1)
```

to be

```
addChild(pCircle_f0s1, 2)
```

From the above, using FIND & REPLACE should ignore the word **f0s1** but I can't do that.
Notice that **f0s1** is batch index started to complete further a lot of items.

Thanks for help